# How to know the Java interfaces an OpenOffice Calc UNO object supports (through queryInterface)

Tags: java, openoffice-calc, uno

I'm developing a "macro" for OpenOffice Calc. As the language, I chose Java, in order to get code assistance in Eclipse. I even wrote a small `ant` build script that compiles and embeds the "macro" in an `*.ods` file. In general, this works fine and surprisingly fast; I'm already using some simple stuff quite successfully.

*BUT*

So often I get stuck because with `UNO`, I need to "query" an interface for any given non-trivial object, to be able to access data / call methods of that object. I.e., I literally need to guess which interfaces a given object may provide. This is *not at all* obvious and not even visible during Java development (through some sort of meta-information, reflection or the like), and also sparsely documented (I downloaded tons of stuff, but I don't find the source or maybe JavaDoc for the interfaces I'm using, like `XButton`, `XPropertySet`, etc. - `XButton` has `setLabel`, but *not* `getLabel` - what??).

There is online documentation (for the most fundamental concepts, which is not bad at all!), *but* it lacks many details that I'm faced with. It always magically stops exactly at the point I need to solve.

I'm willing to look at the `C++` code to get a clue what interfaces an object (e.g. the button / event I'm currently stuck with) may provide. Confusingly, the `C++` class and file names don't exactly match the Java interfaces. It's *almost* what I'm looking for, but then in Java I don't really find the equivalent, *or* calling `queryInterface` on a given object returns `null`.. It's becoming a bit frustrating.

How are the UNO Java interfaces generated? Is there some kind of documentation in the code that serves as the origin for the generated (Java) code?

I think I *really* need to know what interfaces are available at which point, in order to become a bit more fluent during *Java-UNO-macro* development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any serious UNO project, use an introspection tool.

As an example, I created a button in Calc, then used the Java [Object Inspector](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Object_Inspector) to browse to the button. 
 Right-clicking and choosing "Add to Source Code" generated the following.

```
import com.sun.star.awt.XControlModel;
import com.sun.star.beans.XPropertySet;
import com.sun.star.container.XIndexAccess;
import com.sun.star.container.XNameAccess;
import com.sun.star.drawing.XControlShape;
import com.sun.star.drawing.XDrawPage;
import com.sun.star.drawing.XDrawPageSupplier;
import com.sun.star.sheet.XSpreadsheetDocument;
import com.sun.star.sheet.XSpreadsheets;
import com.sun.star.uno.AnyConverter;
import com.sun.star.uno.UnoRuntime;
import com.sun.star.uno.XInterface;

//...
public void codesnippet(XInterface _oUnoEntryObject){
try{
    XSpreadsheetDocument xSpreadsheetDocument =  (XSpreadsheetDocument) UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XSpreadsheetDocument.class, _oUnoEntryObject);
    XSpreadsheets xSpreadsheets = xSpreadsheetDocument.getSheets();
    XNameAccess xNameAccess =  (XNameAccess) UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XNameAccess.class, xSpreadsheets);
    Object oName = xNameAccess.getByName("Sheet1");
    XDrawPageSupplier xDrawPageSupplier =  (XDrawPageSupplier) UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XDrawPageSupplier.class, oName);
    XDrawPage xDrawPage = xDrawPageSupplier.getDrawPage();
    XIndexAccess xIndexAccess =  (XIndexAccess) UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XIndexAccess.class, xDrawPage);
    Object oIndex = xIndexAccess.getByIndex(0);
    XControlShape xControlShape =  (XControlShape) UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XControlShape.class, oIndex);
    XControlModel xControlModel = xControlShape.getControl();
    XPropertySet xPropertySet =  (XPropertySet) UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XPropertySet.class, xControlModel);
    String sLabel = AnyConverter.toString(xPropertySet.getPropertyValue("Label"));
}catch (com.sun.star.beans.UnknownPropertyException e){
    e.printStackTrace(System.out);
    //Enter your Code here...
}catch (com.sun.star.lang.WrappedTargetException e2){
    e2.printStackTrace(System.out);
    //Enter your Code here...
}catch (com.sun.star.lang.IllegalArgumentException e3){
    e3.printStackTrace(System.out);
    //Enter your Code here...
}
}
//...
```

Python-UNO may be better than Java because it does not require querying specific interfaces.  Also XrayTool and MRI are easier to use than the Java Object Inspector.

Comment: This is great! Thank you so much. The Python hint is also good, I was already suspecting the non-Java/-C++ approaches to allow for an easier access. Thank you!